# Drawing objects in aligned to face normal in OpenGL

Tags: math, opengl, 3d

I am trying to draw normal handle (a tall rectangle shape up to now) on geometry faces, in the center of face and pointing along normal.

I am doing it with the code below:

```
Vec3 up(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Vec3 angle_to_rotate = up.cross(face_normal);
double dot = up.dot(normal);
float rotate_angle = std::acos(dot);

Mat4 matrix;
matrix.translate(face_center.x, face_center.y, face_center.z);
matrix.rotate(angle_to_rotate, rotate_angle);

glMultMatrixd(matrix.copyGL());
```

then I am drawing a tall cube in world space (y up).

This works ok sometimes, but sometimes (45 angles in two dimension) it fails, or the angle direction is correct, but the rectangle looks like rotated on z-axis and is not aligned right.

Is this correct way of achieving drawing objects aligned with (maybe in future perpendicular to too) normal in OpenGL or is there a better way?

Comment: "looks like rotated on z-axis and is not aligned right" : Do you have link to screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The cross-product of two normalized vectors is not normalized itself. The length of the vector is actually the sinus of the rotation angle.

You could use that to get a more accurate value for the angle:

```cpp
Vec3 axis = up.cross(face_normal);
float angle = std::atan2(axis.length(), up.dot(face_normal));
axis = axis.normalize();
```